# Entity Framework opens new connection for each request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When I make multiple requests to SQL using single context, EF opens new connection for each request. For example, this code grabbing several lists from database:

```
using(MyContext nctx = new MyContext())
{
    var dictAllSelects = new Dictionary<string, SelectList>(){
        {"sl_task_id", new SelectList(nctx.Tasks.ToArray(), "id", "name")},
        {"sl_task_item_id", new SelectList(nctx.TaskItems.ToArray(), "id", "name")},
        {"sl_unit_id", new SelectList(nctx.Units.ToArray(), "id", "name")},
        {"sl_unit_type_id", new SelectList(nctx.UnitTypes.ToArray(), "id", "name")}
    };
}
```

EF creates a new connection to the database for this queries apiece, that is four times in this case:

> 27.09.2014 16:27:54 [SQL]: Opened connection at 27.09.2014 16:27:54 +04:00
>
> 27.09.2014 16:27:54 [SQL]: SELECT [Extent1].[id] AS [id], [Extent1].[name] AS [name],  [Extent1].[task_id] AS [task_id] FROM [dbo].[TaskItems] AS [Extent1]
>
> 27.09.2014 16:27:54 [SQL]: -- Executing at 27.09.2014 16:27:54 +04:00
>
> 27.09.2014 16:27:54 [SQL]: -- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader
>
> 27.09.2014 16:27:54 [SQL]: Closed connection at 27.09.2014 16:27:54 +04:00
>
> 27.09.2014 16:27:54 [SQL]: Opened connection at 27.09.2014 16:27:54 +04:00
>
> 27.09.2014 16:27:54 [SQL]: SELECT [Extent1].[id] AS [id], [Extent1].[name] AS [name], [Extent1].[city] AS [city], [Extent1].[unit_type_id] AS [unit_type_id] FROM [dbo].[Units] AS [Extent1]
>
> 27.09.2014 16:27:54 [SQL]: -- Executing at 27.09.2014 16:27:54 +04:00
>
> 27.09.2014 16:27:54 [SQL]: -- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader
>
> 27.09.2014 16:27:54 [SQL]:  Closed connection at 27.09.2014 16:27:54 +04:00
>
> etc...

Is there any way to control EF dbcontext connections and/or force it open single connection until disposed or until is told to close it?

Comment: Are you using connection pooling ?

Comment: By default. But I needed to fit all request in a single connection, because in real there no less than 15 requests at best.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I was very inadvertent. It was rather simple:

```
using(MyContext nctx = new MyContext())
{
    nctx.Database.Connection.Open();
    var dictAllSelects = new Dictionary<string, SelectList>(){
        {"sl_task_id", new SelectList(nctx.Tasks.ToArray(), "id", "name")},
        {"sl_task_item_id", new SelectList(nctx.TaskItems.ToArray(), "id", "name")},
        {"sl_unit_id", new SelectList(nctx.Units.ToArray(), "id", "name")},
        {"sl_unit_type_id", new SelectList(nctx.UnitTypes.ToArray(), "id", "name")}
    };
    nctx.Database.Connection.Close();
}
```

Needed to read MSDN more carefully.